# SQL Query - Ensuring my code is correct/Assistance with multiple queries in one Query (Subquerying)

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I have a query today regarding SQL.

Basically here is what I am trying to do (this will also be useful for a couple other tables I have in this DB)

Table 1 = Members
Table 2 = Payments

Essentially trying to insert record into 1 table however have the query also copy over a memberID field if it's present for the individual.

```
INSERT INTO Payments (FirstName, LastName, PaymentMade)
VALUES ('',  '', ''); AND UPDATE Payments
SET Payments.MemberID = Members.MemberID
FROM Members INNER JOIN Members ON Payments.MemberID = Members.MemberID;
```

Question is: Have I performed this correctly or have I missed a critical step here?

Many thanks! :)

Comment: That is not valid syntax, so it won't work. You'd know that if you made an effort to use it. Finding a good basic SQL tutorial would be very helpful.

Comment: None of that SQL makes sense. Can't run multiple actions in one statement. Why save names into Payments and not just account or member ID? Why use code and not just enter data into a form bound to table?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want to insert data from Table1 into Table2.

```
INSERT INTO table2 (column1, column2, column3, ...)
SELECT column1, column2, column3, ...
FROM table1
```

Use a Where condition for filtering out unwanted records.

```
INSERT INTO table2 (column1, column2, column3, ...)
SELECT column1, column2, column3, ...
FROM table1
WHERE condition;
```